# How to remove element from the list?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I have written a command that output a list of hostnames, e.g. :

```
clab148node11
clab148node12
clab148node15
clab148node16
```

Now, I would like to remove those nodes that do not respond to ping. For now I have something like this :

```
for node in $nodes
do
         result=$(ping -c 1 $node; echo $?)
done
```

Now how do I remove nodes that have the `$result` different than 0 ?

Comment: Is it a requirement to _remove_ from the list? I prefer to build a new list instead: `error=(); for node in $nodes; do ping -c 1 $node || error+=($node); done`

Comment: @manatwork Well it's also a solution but if it's possible to be done without then I would like to see it as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd prefer to build a new list and replace an old one with a new:

```
nodes="127.0.0.1 1.2.3.4 1.2.3.4 "
nodes_out=
for node in $nodes
do 
    ping -c 1 $node >/dev/null 2>&1 && nodes_out+=$node
done
nodes=$nodes_out
```

Answer (score 2):

like @manatwork said, it looks simpler and safer to build a new list with the valid nodes.

However, as "$nodes" is evaluated before the first iteration of the for loop, it should be possible to change it during that same loop:

```
$ nodes="127.0.0.1 1.2.3.4 1.2.3.4 "
$ for node in $nodes; do
      result=$(ping -c 1 $node >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; echo $?);
      if [ "$result" -ne 0 ]; 
      then    nodes=$(echo $nodes | sed -e "s/ *$node */ /"); 
      fi;
      echo result=$result node=$node nodes=$nodes ;    
  done ;
```

Notice : my sed replace `[space]$node[space]` or `$node[space]` or `[space]$node` to work in all cases depending on the position of `$node` in the `$nodes` list (If its in the middle, or the first or the last element, space(s) before and after it will be either present or not). And it only replace 1 occurence at a time, but you could add a final `/g` to get rid of all occurences at once.

This outputs:

```
result=0 node=127.0.0.1 nodes=127.0.0.1 1.2.3.4 1.2.3.4
result=1 node=1.2.3.4 nodes=127.0.0.1 1.2.3.4
result=1 node=1.2.3.4 nodes=127.0.0.1
```

Comment: you can use `nodes=${nodes/$node}` instead expression with `sed` in `bash`, `ksh`, etc. spaces don't matter in such list.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to simply use an inverse grep to find all occurrences in the list **not** matching the host:

```
for node in $nodes
do
    if ! `ping -c 1 $node > /dev/null 2>&1`; then 
        nodes="`echo \"$nodes\" | grep -v \"$node\"`"
    fi
done
```